# Seeing which jars classes are coming from

Tags: java, linux, unix, jar, rhel

I am using a script to run a Java process that uses a TON of jars in RHEL.

Is there an easy command to see which jars classes are being loaded from?

For instance:

com.asdf.asdf.DummyClass==> /path/to/arf.jar

or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeap

```
java -verbose:class  x.y.Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the class' classLoader. See code samples here:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0391.html